# Losing my react page history after reload

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So im building a react app.
Im using Link and react router dom not swap pages in the nav bar.
When ever i press reload on any page but home on the live release. I loose all my history and get page 404 error.
I am not sure why this is happening.
In package.json i have set my home page.
m y .htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

My routes and links are simple

```
<Route path='/' element={<NewHome />} />
<Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage />} />

<Link to='/'>Home</Link>
   
<li className='cursor-pointer transition ease-in-out duration-200 text-colour-med hover:text-slate-500 active:text-slate-500'>
 <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
</li>
```

How can i get my page to remember where it has been

I tried changing my homepage to "."

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser session, if you haven't saved data to somewhere more permanent such as local or session storage then everything is lost on a page reload

Comment: i understand that for state getting lost, but i dont see how im losing my url trail

Comment: Are you using createBrowserHistory or similar? I know it's different in different versions of React